# LINQ: Customize the count method

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I'm trying to implement a custom LinQ `Count()` method. Basically what I'm trying to achieve here is before calling the Count method, I want to filter out all elements that have the property `IsDeleted` set to true. So, I created an extension class and I added these methods:

```
public static int Count2<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, bool> selector)
    where T : Model
{
    return source.Where(x => !x.IsDeleted).Count(selector);
}

public static int Count2<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, Expression<Func<T, bool>> selector)
    where T : Model
{
    return source.Where(x => !x.IsDeleted).Count(selector);
}

public static int Count2<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
    where T : Model
{
    return source.Count(x => !x.IsDeleted);
}

public static int Count2<T>(this IQueryable<T> source)
    where T : Model
{
    return source.Count(x => !x.IsDeleted);
}
```

This works just find for local collections, but when executing this command for instance:

```
ListOfModels.Sum(x => x.PropertyThatIsAList.Count2())
```

and `ListOfModels` is an instance of `IQueryable`, i.e. it has to be executed in the database, it gives me this error:

> The LINQ expression 'Sum()' could not be translated and will be evaluated locally.

I looked around on the web and I saw some answers saying I have to implement the `IQueryableProvider` but I think there is no need to go into such complicated path since the `Sum()` and `Count()` are translatable, I only need to count conditionally. Is it possible, and if it is, can anyone give me a clue on how to do it?

Comment: These LINQ expressions you send to DB are then translated to DB queries. In your case `System.Linq` doesn't know what to do with your extension methods (though they are translatable) unless you tell it what to do with them which is implementing `IQueryProvider`.

Comment: @Emad But if I do translate them using the `IQueryProvider`, this would make them database-specific. This is okay if I was creating new commands, but since they are translatable I'm thinking there's gotta be a way to do them without losing the ability to execute them on different DBs.

Comment: That's not true. There are already a lot of `IQueryProviders` in `System.Linq` which do work on all databases. The generality is in your implementation, not intrinsic.

Comment: @Emad So what should I do then if I have to use already existing `IQueryProvider `s?

Comment: You should use internal methods like normal count and then do your process in memory. You can't have it database level.

Comment: Does it work correctly when you do "ListOfModels.Sum(x => x.PropertyThatIsAList.Where(c => !c.IsDeleted).Count())" ?

Comment: @Evk Yes it does if I'm not using the extension method

Comment: And which ORM you use (and which version)? Entity Framework, linq to sql?

Comment: @Evk EntityFramwork core (version 7)

Comment: EF Core is in a very immature state where many things does not work as they should. In this case for example, regular Entity Framework will translate query from my comment just fine to a database query. Using separate extensions methods (even if you've managed to somehow translate them) would not help anyway in this case. I personally just avoid EF Core because of such things.

Comment: @Evk But EF Core can translate your query to a database query. I wanted to have the `Count2()` extension method since the condition `!x => x.IsDeleted` happens alot. Anyway, how would u do this extension method in regular EF?

Comment: Well in comment above you said in EF Core it will be executed locally... Anyway, it's too long to describe in comment, but you will have to use ExpressionVisitor and replace a call to your Count2() method in expression tree. How to intercept EF Core expression query is briefly described here: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/4048.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you instead of customizing all LinQ methods use an extended method like `Validate()`:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Validate<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list) where T: IDeleteable
{
    return list.Where(w => !w.IsDeleted);
}
```

That `IDeleteable` interface is like this:

```
public interface IDeleteable
{
    bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
}
```

Then use it before other methods.

Comment: This will be executed locally since it has to translate the `Validate()` method.

Comment: I can't understand what do you mean !?, I can add that  calling `list.Validate().Count()` is more readable, reusable and flexible than your approach that `list.Count2()` has no input expression to use LinQ abilities.

Comment: It is the same! The one in your example will be executed in the database just like mine. But, this code won't be executed in the database: `list.Sum(x => x.AnotherList.Validate().Count())`. It will only be executed locally. Becuase the method `Validate()` needs to be translated since LinQ doesn't understand it

Comment: An extension method is in a static class that is accessible in an assembly globally not locally, And I test above method and LinQ understand it without any exception!!. It is not translated to some special SQL code it is a simple `.Where()` statement that added to LinQ ;).

Comment: Yeah, I know it is a simple `.Where()` statement but when it is inside an `Expression` like the example I gave you, the `.Validate()` will be treated as a standard LinQ command. Since it is not a standard command, LinQ won't be able to translate it to SQL. So what happens is that the data is fetched from the database into the memory and then the `.Where()` inside the `.Validate()` is executed on the data residing on memory. Hope that clarifies the problem :)

Comment: Oh, I found out what are you talking about, your problem is not about LinQ to entities your problem is about using extension methods in LinQ to database like using EF, To solve that problem we need to know how do you call database for finding a proper translatable code, i.e for EF you need to use [CLR methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738681.aspx) ;).

Comment: Yeah that's what I'm trying to accomplish but I don't know how

Comment: Title of your questions is so different from what you want, I can suggest you to ask another question about that ;).